# Python else if has 'invalid syntax'. works on Linux

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a piece of code that works on Linux, but when I try to run it on windows, I get an invalid syntax error:

```
def testHSPresent():
    if os.path.exists('.highScores.hs'):
        print "Highscores Present!"
    else:<<--------------------error on this line (this marker not in actual code)
        hs = open(".highScores.hs", "w")
        hs.write(str("0000"))
        hs.write('\n')
```

Comment: Your code is not Python 3 compatible.

Comment: print is a function in python3. Try print("Highscores Present!")

Comment: Using 2.7.6 code on 3.4 . Thanks for the help!